# Copy - Paste Clipboard (Right Click Menu) - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, clipboard, right-click

I do not do much programming so I thought I would ask you guys. I am looking at making some kind of chrome extension which enables me to copy multiple things. For example instead of just the normal copy and paste buttons. I want "copy1, copy2, copy3" and then a paste button for each of the copy buttons. I also am hoping I could put it in the right click menu so that I can highlight some text right click, click copy1 and then move on to the next text click copy2 and then when I am all done. I can click "paste1" which would paste "copy1", "paste2" would paste "copy2"and continue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you would have to:

1. use the chrome.contextMenus API to add the buttons to the context menu
2. add an event listener to each button
3. copy the item into storage using the chrome.storage API
4. paste the item by getting it from the chrome.storage API

Comment: But how to paste ?